# Easy way to import CSV to SQL Server with quotes in fields

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms

I'm trying to import a CSV file, which includes commas and quotes in the fields, into a SQL Server database. There's about a million questions and topics about it online, but none really works. I've come to understand that when it comes to CSV there are slightly different standards, but SSMS doesn't seem to be able to import either and I feel like there really should be a convenient way.

The files contain free text strings where they use both double-quotations and commas within the fields.

Here's the test CSV file I'm using:

```
"Value 1","Notes"
""8-pooln" grupp 7:6 To11:13","As extracted"
"""8-pooln"" grupp 7:6 To11:13","With escaped quotes"
"""""""""""8-pooln"""""""""""""""" grupp 7:6 To11:13","With loads of quotes"
```

I used a 3rd-party program extract the data to CSV. So the first record is how I got it from that program. According to some site you need to escape double-quotes within a field by adding another double-quote, that's what you see at record 2. The last one just contains a lot of them for testing. I also used another application to validate the file as CSV, where 2nd and 3rd records pass.

By using the SSMS Import Wizard I get:

```
_Value_1_,_Notes_
8-pooln" grupp 7:6 To11:13,As extracted
8-pooln"" grupp 7:6 To11:13,With escaped quotes
8-pooln"""""""""""""""" grupp 7:6 To11:13,With loads of quotes
```

So double-quotations in the start are all always ignored regardless how many they are. I haven't found any settings that could change this at all.

I've also tried to manually write an SQL command such as:

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Which gives us:

```
Value_1,Notes
"Value 1","Notes"
""8-pooln" grupp 7:6 To11:13","As extracted"
"""8-pooln"" grupp 7:6 To11:13","With escaped quotes"
"""""""""""8-pooln"""""""""""""""" grupp 7:6 To11:13","With loads of quotes"
```

It only recognizes commas and newlines as any type of control character and there doesn't seem to be any additional lines you can add to fix it.

Lastly I found some solution where you can write a "format file", where you can basically define the column delimiter for each column manually. Which would probably work, but I have way over 50 columns for one file and about 20 files.

I also found a possible solution in settings for SSMS Import Wizard but it's for an old version and looks like it no longer exists.

To clarify:

- The fields have both commas and double-quotes in them so the double-quotes opening and closing the fields are necessary. I rather not change anything at all (like from double- to single-quotes) as I don't know exactly what the values mean.
- There are about 20 files, one with 95000 records and 50+ columns. Creating format-files seems unreasonable.
- It's really not that bad formatted files. SSMS intuitively really should be able to import this without any fix. I can maybe live with manually editing the CSV-file to match the standards (as I did with the 2nd record in my test file).

At this point I am just happy with insight of why it just doesn't work or why my problem seem to be unique.

Comment: Except for the second line of your example, which doesn't have properly doubled quotes within the quoted string, this will import the test data: https://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#import

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if using SSIS is an option for you, but if so importing data with quotes within the text fields would be fairly easy to do.  An overview of this process is below.

- Create an OLE DB connection to the SQL Server instance where the destination table is. 
  This can be done by right-clicking in the Connections Managers window, selecting **New Connection...** then choosing the OLE DB option.  Configure the login credentials and initial catalog for where the data will be loaded to.
- Next create a Flat File Connection Manager.  For File Name field, navigate to an existing folder and select an example data file.  If you don't see the file, change to file extension to all files in file explorer.  Choose `Delimited` for the Format field and check the "Columns names in the first data row" option if this applies to your file.  Set the header row delimiter appropriately.  Judging by your example, I'm guessing you would use the carriage return/line field combination, which is the `{CR}{LF}` value.
- On the Columns pane, set the row delimiter accordingly, which also appears to be `{CR}{LF}` from your sample.  For column delimiter, use the `,`.  This will apply to all columns in the file thus you won't need to set this for each field.  I couldn't quite tell by your question, but if a `,` separates all fields then use this option, otherwise type `Mixed` for the column delimiter.  This option may not appear in the drop-down, but tying it will allow you to use different delimiters for each column.  More on this follows in the item belows
- In the Advanced pane, add names, data types, and lengths for the columns.  If you're unsure about what SSIS data types correspond to the SQL Server ones see the mapping table in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017) which shows which data types relate to each other.  If you used the `Mixed` option above, here you can set the delimiter in the `ColumnDelimiter` field for each column.  You can type in values here as well.  For example, if fields will always be separated by a certain combination of characters this can be used as well.
- After the connection manager has been created, create a Data Flow Task and within this add a Flat File Source component.  Use the connection manager that you just created for the connection manager of this component.
- Next add either an OLE DB or SQL Server destination.  I've found that SQL Server destination tend to perform better, but of course this can vary between different environments.  Use the OLE DB connection manager that was created for the destination SQL Server instance and map the columns on the Mappings pane.  Connect to Flat File Source to the SQL Server Destination and you can now load the data into your table from source file.
- If this is something you will be doing on a regular basis, look into setting this up as a SQL Agent job.  You can find more details on this process [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-2017).